# Galvanically isolated voltage PCB track clearance requirements

Tags: pcb, clearance, creepage

I am designing a PCB to switch high voltage (440VAC) from a microcontroller.

In this project, the 440VAC voltage is galvanically isolated from the microcontroller circuit. I am using an opto-coupler to pass signal from microcontroller to the control circuit of the MOSFET.

Since there is no common voltage reference between both voltages, can I place both the traces closer?

My circuit is based on the following:

[image: AC and DC have separate lines]

Comment: Closer does not imply isolation!

Comment: As a rule of thumb reckon a minimum of 8 mm creepage (along surfaces) and 4 mm clearance (through the air) separation for that sort of voltage. Your optocoupler ought to be wide enough to achieve that.

Comment: Two diodes in your bridge are of course redundant.

Comment: I’d suggest getting the circuit correct before even considering the pcb. Are your resistors rated for the voltage? Protection for the mosfets? Drive for the mosfets?

Comment: @Kartman I have the circuit working on protoboard. I want to take it to the PCB

Comment: see how long it works in the field or burns your house down.

Comment: @Neil_UK, I am designing with a 2mm clearance with conformal coating. However, I am unable to provide isolation for one net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These creepage and clearance distances are specified in IEC 61439. And your assumption about them having no common voltage is incorrect: they both ultimately reference ground, even if the path is indirect.

More about ISO 61439 here: https://blog.se.com/power-management-metering-monitoring-power-quality/2018/06/06/clearances-and-creepage-distances-in-lv-electrical-switchboards/

Comment: Hi @hacktastical, they both don't share the same ground.

Comment: @SKGadi They do **ultimately** share a reference ground, even if the path is indirect.

Comment: If you don't select the reference ground, the circuit will pick for you.

Comment: Charge finds a way. It always does, unless you plan accordingly. Even then, *some* charge finds a way, the trick is that it's not enough to kill you. You'll note that there are both humidity and altitude parameters in IEC 61439. That's because air isn't a perfect insulator, and it's even less perfect at high altitude.

Comment: @hacktastical, with my understanding I can guess why humidity effect, but I am unable to understand how the altitude effect the air insulation.

Comment: @SKGadi Lower air pressure (up to a point) means larger mean-free-path for ions, which means lower breakdown electric field before you can start an arc. High voltage switchgear often uses SF6 gas at many atmospheres pressure to improve dielectric strength. See [Paschens Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paschen%27s_law) if you're interested.